# Expected to return a value at the end of this function array-callback-return in React JS

Tags: reactjs

```js
render() {

        const rowLeft = [];
        const rowRight = [];
        let a = this.props.ntn;
        

       Object.keys(this.props.ntn).map((keyName, keyIndex) =>{

        if (keyName === "_id" || keyName === "name" || keyName === "description" || keyName === "instant" || keyName === "active") {
                  if (keyName === "beacon" || keyName === "group") {

            return rowLeft.push(<InfoRow notification={keyName} notificationValue={a[keyName].name.toString()} key={keyIndex}/>)
          } 

        else if (a[keyName].offers) {

            return rowLeft.push(<InfoRow notification={keyName} notificationValue={a[keyName].offers.toString()} key={keyIndex}/>)
          }

          else {

            return rowLeft.push(<InfoRow notification={keyName} notificationValue={a[keyName].toString()} key={keyIndex}/>)
         }}
       
       });

       Object.keys(this.props.ntn).map((keyName, keyIndex) =>{

        if (keyName === "levelType" || keyName === "triggeringEvents" || keyName === "type" || keyName === "beacon" || keyName === "inbox") {
                  if (keyName === "beacon" || keyName === "group") {

            return rowRight.push(<InfoRow notification={keyName} notificationValue={a[keyName].name.toString()} key={keyIndex}/>)
          } 

        else if (a[keyName].offers) {

            return rowRight.push(<InfoRow notification={keyName} notificationValue={a[keyName].offers.toString()} key={keyIndex}/>)
          }

          else {

            return rowRight.push(<InfoRow notification={keyName} notificationValue={a[keyName].toString()} key={keyIndex}/>)
         }}
       
       });

        return (
```

i did something like this
actually I'm fetching values and showing all the details on the page
what the thing is now I'm getting this warning
"Expected to return a value at the end of this function  array-callback-return in React JS"
Any solution? How to deal with it?

Comment: There's nothing returned from the function in the code snippet you presented.

Comment: ^ tru. Post the rest of the snippet or add a valid `return` statement

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**TLDR**: The simplest fix is to use `Object.keys(this.props.ntn).forEach` instead of `.map` and make all `return rowLeft.push` just `rowLeft.push`.

**Long answer**:

The ESLint [array-callback-return](http://eslint.org/docs/rules/array-callback-return) warning makes sure that you always return a value from methods like `map`, `filter` and `reduce`. You are not returning a value in you first `if` which has the following form:

```
if condition1 {
   if condition2 {
      return
   }
   // here you are missing a return
}
else if ...
```

However, you are not using `map` correctly. You should be using `forEach`.

Of course, your code can be rewritten using `map`, consider:

```
const {ntn} = this.props;

const rowLeft = Object.keys(ntn).map((keyName, keyIndex) => {
   const value = ntn[keyName];
   let notificationValue;   

   if (['_id', 'name', 'description', 'instant', 'active', 'beacon', 'group'].includes(keyName) {
       notificationValue = value.name.toString();
   } else if (value.offers) {
       notificationValue = value.offers.toString();
   } else {
       notificationValue = value.toString();
   }

   return (
      <InfoRow notification={keyName} notificationValue={notificationValue} key={keyIndex}/>
   );
});
```

Also note that in your example the first condition *is never executed* because it would require `keyName` to have *two values at once*. I have replaced it with one condition which I guess is what you want.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43694280/how-to-show-a-getting-started-popup-in-react-js

Comment: `Object.keys(this.props.ntn).forEach` Works