# How to show a getting started popup in react js?

Tags: reactjs

i just wanted to know how to show dialog box or popup using react js
i had made a page and now what i want is to show the instructions of getting started like we see in several sites
On clicking next button it will show next dialog box and on close it will close the popup
Also the dialog box or popup i want in the center of the screen

Comment: you can use `material-ui component Dialog box`, easy to use and it will fulfil your requirement also, check this: http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/dialog

Comment: will it work in react js?

Comment: these components are only for react js check the sample examples and their code.

Comment: not working..
Can you provide any running code?

Comment: using CSS, not a react question really.

Comment: How with that then?
it is a react question actually

Comment: @Piyush Really, it's not. If you know how to create a dialog box in plain HTML/CSS, it won't be a problem for you to create it in react.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-modal

This solution worked for me very well

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using materual-ui in react.

1. npm install material-ui --save
2. Follow this [link](http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/dialog) to add dialog in your react app

Comment: If you dont know about material-ui then visit this link https://www.npmjs.com/package/material-ui

Comment: That's what I'm asking if you can provide any actually